# Evaluate $\int\limits_0^{\sqrt 2 } {\frac{1}{{3{a^2} + 2}}\frac{{\arctan \left( {\sqrt {{a^2} + 1} } \right)}}{{\sqrt {{a^2} + 1} }}da}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to evaluate this:
$$I=\int\limits_0^{\sqrt 2 } {\frac{1}{{3{a^2} + 2}}\frac{{\arctan \left( {\sqrt {{a^2} + 1} } \right)}}{{\sqrt {{a^2} + 1} }}da} $$
It looks like Ahmed's integral, but I don't know how to solve this.
Here is what I tried:
$$\eqalign{
  & I\left( b \right) = \int\limits_0^{\sqrt 2 } {\frac{1}{{3{a^2} + 2}}\frac{{\arctan \left( {b\sqrt {{a^2} + 1} } \right)}}{{\sqrt {{a^2} + 1} }}da} ,I\left( 0 \right) = 0  \cr 
  & I'\left( b \right) = \int\limits_0^{\sqrt 2 } {\frac{1}{{\left( {3{a^2} + 2} \right)\left( {1 + {b^2}\left( {{a^2} + 1} \right)} \right)}}da}  = \left. {\left( {\frac{{\sqrt 6 }}{{2{b^2} + 6}}{{\tan }^{ - 1}}\left( {\sqrt {\frac{3}{2}} a} \right) - \frac{b}{{\sqrt {{b^2} + 1} \left( {{b^2} + 3} \right)}}{{\tan }^{ - 1}}\left( {\frac{{ab}}{{\sqrt {{b^2} + 1} }}} \right)} \right)} \right|_0^{\sqrt 2 }  \cr 
  &  = \frac{{\pi \sqrt {\frac{2}{3}} }}{{2{b^2} + 6}} - \frac{b}{{\left( {{b^2} + 3} \right)\sqrt {{b^2} + 1} }}{\tan ^{ - 1}}\left( {\frac{{\sqrt 2 b}}{{\sqrt {{b^2} + 1} }}} \right),{\text{ integrate both sides from 0 to }}1  \cr 
  & I\left( 1 \right){\text{ = }}\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {\frac{{\pi \sqrt {\frac{2}{3}} }}{{2{b^2} + 6}} - \frac{b}{{\left( {{b^2} + 3} \right)\sqrt {{b^2} + 1} }}{{\tan }^{ - 1}}\left( {\frac{{\sqrt 2 b}}{{\sqrt {{b^2} + 1} }}} \right)} \right)db = \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{{18\sqrt 2 }} - } {\text{ }}\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{b}{{\left( {{b^2} + 3} \right)\sqrt {{b^2} + 1} }}{{\tan }^{ - 1}}\left( {\frac{{\sqrt 2 b}}{{\sqrt {{b^2} + 1} }}} \right)db}  \cr} $$

At this  point, I don't know how to process further. May I ask for help? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try to substitute $t=\sqrt{a^2+1}$? It looks like it simplifies your integral somewhat.

Comment: @BrunoB yes, fixed it, thank you.

Comment: If $2=3$ the problem is simple ! Have a look at the edit of my second answer. Nice problem ! (+1)

Comment: [Numerically](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0.315018175678143867861278792257646766558882852508071356805539780131106947627881957606514643698057460675355603456573970816995547308857447892037149055-13π%5E2%2F%28288+√2%29+), the integral is $\frac{13\pi^2}{288\sqrt2}$. Probably an evaluation mirroring that of Ahmed’s integral will work

Comment: Is this result feasible?
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{3t^{2}+5}\ \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{1+t^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}dt=\frac{59\gamma+71\ln2-65\ln3}{76}$$
or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: @BlackEmperor $$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{3t^{2}+3}\ \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{1+t^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}dt=\frac{1}{108} \left(-9 \sqrt{2} \pi +4 \sqrt{6} \pi +36 \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\right)$$ This is why I thought about series.

Comment: Also Equivalent to proving,
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\left(\sin x+\cos x\right)\arctan\left(\sin x+\cos x\right)}{2-\sin\left(2x\right)}dx=\frac{7}{96}\pi^{2}$$

Comment: IBP on the last $b$-integral gives a slightly simpler-looking form,$$\frac{17\pi^2}{144\sqrt2}-\frac1{\sqrt2}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\arctan\sqrt{2-b^2}}{1+b^2}\,db}$$and the indicated integral agrees with @BlackEmperor's

Comment: You may also find the strategies mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330757/proving-int-sqrt-frac351-frac-arctan-x-sqrt2-x2-1-left3-x) helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}\frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x^2+1}}{(3x^2+2)\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx\\
=& \ \int_0^{\sqrt2} \tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\ d\bigg(-\frac1{\sqrt2}\cot^{-1}\frac x{\sqrt{2x^2+2}} \bigg)\\
\overset{ibp}=& \ \frac{\pi^2}{72\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt2}\int_0^{\sqrt2} \frac{x\cot^{-1}\frac x{\sqrt{2x^2+2}} }{(x^2+2)\sqrt{x^2+1}} \ dx\\
 =& \ \frac{\pi^2}{72\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt2}\int_0^{\sqrt2} \int_0^{\sqrt2} \frac{x^2 }{(x^2+2)(x^2+y^2 +x^2y^2 )} \ dy \ dx\\
 =& \ \frac{\pi^2}{72\sqrt2}+\frac1{2\sqrt2}\int_0^\sqrt2 \int_0^\sqrt2 \bigg( \frac{x^2 }{x^2+2}+\frac{y^2}{y^2+2} \bigg)\frac1{x^2+y^2 +x^2y^2 }\ dy \ dx\\
 =& \ \frac{\pi^2}{72\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt2}\int_0^\sqrt2 \int_0^\sqrt2 \frac{1}{(x^2+2)(y^2+2)}\ dy \ dx\\
 =& \ \frac{\pi^2}{72\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt2}\left( \frac\pi{4\sqrt2}\right)^2
=\frac{13\pi^2}{288\sqrt2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 9):

Given the questioner's knowledge regarding techniques of integration, I shall omit the calculation of the following integrals. They should be easy for OP.
\begin{align*}
&I_1=\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}{\frac{1}{\left( 3x^2+2 \right) \sqrt{x^2+1}}}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{2}}
\\
&I_2=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\cos \left( \theta \right)}{1+2\sin ^2\left( \theta \right)}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{2}\cos \left( \theta \right) \right) \mathrm{d}\theta}=\frac{\pi ^2}{12\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}
So **HERE WE GO**.
\begin{align*}
I=&\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}{\frac{\mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{x^2+1} \right)}{\left( 3x^2+2 \right) \sqrt{x^2+1}}}\mathrm{d}x
\\
=&\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}{\frac{1}{\left( 3x^2+2 \right) \sqrt{x^2+1}}}\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}{\frac{1}{\left( 3x^2+2 \right) \sqrt{x^2+1}}}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \right) \mathrm{d}x
\\
=&\frac{\pi}{2}I_1-\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}{\int_0^1{\frac{1}{\left( t^2+x^2+1 \right) \left( 3x^2+2 \right)}}\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x}
\\
\stackrel{x\rightsquigarrow \sqrt{2}x}{=}&\frac{\pi ^2}{12\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^1{\int_0^1{\frac{1}{\left( t^2+2x^2+1 \right) \left( 3x^2+1 \right)}}\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x}
\\
=&\frac{\pi ^2}{12\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^1{\int_0^1{\frac{1}{\left( t^2+2x^2+1 \right) \left( 3x^2+1 \right)}\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}t}
\\
=&\frac{\pi ^2}{12\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^1{\frac{1}{3t^2+1}\int_0^1{\left( \frac{3}{3x^2+1}-\frac{2}{2x^2+t^2+1} \right) \mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}t}
\\
=&\frac{\pi ^2}{12\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^1{\frac{1}{3t^2+1}\int_0^1{\left( \frac{1}{x^2+\frac{1}{3}}-\frac{1}{x^2+\frac{t^2+1}{2}} \right) \mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}t}
\\
=&\frac{\pi ^2}{12\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^1{\frac{1}{3t^2+1}\left( \sqrt{3}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{3} \right) -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} \right) \right) \mathrm{d}t}
\\
=&\frac{\pi ^2}{12\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{6}}\int_0^1{\frac{1}{t^2+\frac{1}{3}}\mathrm{d}t}+\int_0^1{\frac{1}{\left( 3t^2+1 \right) \sqrt{t^2+1}}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} \right) \mathrm{d}t}
\\
=&\frac{\pi ^2}{12\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi ^2}{9\sqrt{2}}+\int_0^1{\frac{1}{\left( 3t^2+1 \right) \sqrt{t^2+1}}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} \right) \mathrm{d}t}
\\
=&\frac{-\pi ^2}{36\sqrt{2}}+\int_0^1{\frac{1}{\left( 3t^2+1 \right) \sqrt{t^2+1}}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} \right) \mathrm{d}t}
\end{align*}
Now, write
\begin{align*}
J=&\int_0^1{\frac{1}{\left( 3t^2+1 \right) \sqrt{t^2+1}}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} \right) \mathrm{d}t}
\\
\stackrel{t=\tan \left( \theta \right)}{=}&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\frac{\sec \left( \theta \right)}{3\tan ^2\left( \theta \right) +1}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sec \left( \theta \right)} \right) \mathrm{d}\theta}
\\
=&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\frac{\cos \left( \theta \right)}{1+2\sin ^2\left( \theta \right)}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{2}\cos \left( \theta \right) \right) \mathrm{d}\theta}
\\
=&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{2}\cos \left( \theta \right) \right) \mathrm{d}}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{2}\sin \left( \theta \right) \right) \right) 
\\
=&\left. \frac{\mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{2}\cos \left( \theta \right) \right) \mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{2}\sin \left( \theta \right) \right)}{\sqrt{2}} \right|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\frac{\sin \left( \theta \right)}{1+2\cos ^2\left( \theta \right)}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{2}\sin \left( \theta \right) \right) \mathrm{d}\theta}
\\
=&\frac{\pi ^2}{16\sqrt{2}}+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\frac{\sin \left( \theta \right)}{1+2\cos ^2\left( \theta \right)}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{2}\sin \left( \theta \right) \right) \mathrm{d}\theta}
\\
\stackrel{\theta \rightsquigarrow \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta}{=}&\frac{\pi ^2}{16\sqrt{2}}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\cos \left( \theta \right)}{1+2\sin ^2\left( \theta \right)}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{2}\cos \left( \theta \right) \right) \mathrm{d}\theta}
\end{align*}
This means that
\begin{align*}
J=&\frac{1}{2}\left( J+J \right) 
\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\frac{\cos \left( \theta \right)}{1+2\sin ^2\left( \theta \right)}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{2}\cos \left( \theta \right) \right) \mathrm{d}\theta}+\frac{\pi ^2}{32\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\cos \left( \theta \right)}{1+2\sin ^2\left( \theta \right)}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{2}\cos \left( \theta \right) \right) \mathrm{d}\theta}
\\
=&\frac{\pi ^2}{32\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\cos \left( \theta \right)}{1+2\sin ^2\left( \theta \right)}\mathrm{arctan} \left( \sqrt{2}\cos \left( \theta \right) \right) \mathrm{d}\theta}
\\
=&\frac{\pi ^2}{32\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi ^2}{24\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}
At the end, we have
$$
I=\frac{-\pi ^2}{36\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi ^2}{32\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi ^2}{24\sqrt{2}}=\frac{13\pi ^2}{288\sqrt{2}}
$$

Comment: Great answer ! What about  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763428/is-it-possible-to-integrate-frac-tan-1tt2n-sqrtt2-1?noredirect=1#comment10124455_4763428  Thanks in advance fr any idea or suggestion. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I could try to find a closed form for $I_0$, probably too hard for me to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\frac{\pi ^2}{18 \sqrt{2}}-\int_0^1 \frac{b \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}
   b}{\sqrt{b^2+1}}\right)}{\sqrt{b^2+1} \left(b^2+3\right)}\,db$$

Let $\frac{t}{\sqrt{2-t^2}}$ and the integral becomes
$$J=\int_0^1 \frac{t \tan ^{-1}(t)}{\sqrt{4-2 t^2} \left(3-t^2\right)}$$ The series expansion of the arctangent does not lead to anything since, if
$$K_n=\int_0^1 \frac{t^{2 n+2}}{(2 n+1) \sqrt{4-2 t^2} \left(3-t^2\right)}\,dt$$
$$(2 n+1)^2\,K_n=\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2n+1}{2};\frac{2n+3}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)
  -$$ $$F_1\left(\frac{2n+1}{2};-\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{2n+3}{2};\frac{1}{2
   },\frac{1}{3}\right)$$ where appear the Gaussian hypergeometric function and the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables.

A full series expansion converges relatively fast to a value close to the value of
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{-n}}{9 n^2-3 n+2}$$ which is
$$\frac{1}{112} \left(\left(7+5 i \sqrt{7}\right) \,
   _2F_1\left(1,1;\frac{11+i \sqrt 7}{6};-1\right)+\left(7-5 i \sqrt{7}\right) \,
   _2F_1\left(1,1;\frac{11-i
   \sqrt{7}}{6} ;-1\right)\right)$$ The absolute error is $3.405\times 10^{-10}$.

*Many thanks to the $\text{ISC}$*

**Edit**

Starting from @Black Emperor's answer

$$J_n=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{du}{\left(1+u^{2}\right)^{n}\left(3u^{2}+2\right)}=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};n,1;\frac{3}{2};-2,-3\right)$$
We also have that
$$S_n=\sum_{l=1}^{n}\left(\frac{\left(2l-2\right)!}{12^{l}\left(l-1\right)!\left(l-1\right)!}\right)$$

$$S_n=\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{6}}-\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{4 \sqrt{\pi } \,\, 3^{n+1} \,\,\Gamma (n+1)} \,  \, \,_2F_1\left(1,n+\frac{1}{2};n+1;\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

*For the fun of approximation*

Write
$${\frac{{\tan^{-1} \left( {\sqrt {{a^2} + 1} } \right)}}{(3a^2+2){\sqrt {{a^2} + 1} }}}=\frac \pi 8+a^2 P_n(a)$$ where $P_n(a)$ is the $[2n,2n]$ Padé approximant, the simplest being
$$P_1=\frac{ -24 \left(20-67 \pi +54 \pi ^2\right)+\left(304-416 \pi +123 \pi   ^2\right) a^2}{64 (81 \pi -60)+64 (129 \pi -112) a^2 }$$ whose error is $\sim\frac{a^6}{110}$.

This leads to an explicit expression which, converted to decimals, is $0.31632$ (relative error of $0.4$%).

The process can continue using (tedious) fraction decompositions but still giving (nasty) explicit formulae.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{result using } P_n\\
 1 & 0.3163196512 \\
 2 & 0.3150283511 \\
 3 & 0.3150183239 \\
 4 & 0.3150181786 \\
 5 & 0.3150181759 \\
 6 & 0.3150181758 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

One thing you could do is to write
$${\frac{{\tan^{-1} \left( {\sqrt {{a^2} + 1} } \right)}}{(3a^2+2){\sqrt {{a^2} + 1} }}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}\right)}{3^{n+1} \left(a^2+1\right)^{n+\frac{3}{2}} }$$ I did not find the formula for general $n$ (they are quite simple) but, if
$$J_n=\int_0^{\sqrt 2} \frac{\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}\right)}{3^{n+1} \left(a^2+1\right)^{n+\frac{3}{2}} }\,da$$ the summation converges quite fast since
$$\frac 3{11}<\frac{J_{n+1}}{J_n}<\frac 13$$

Summing the first ten terms leads to $0.31502$

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer but hopefully someone takes it from here.

---

Using,
$$\arctan \left(x\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\left(3t^{2}+2\right)\sqrt{t^{2}+1}}dt}_{\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{2}}}-\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{3t^{2}+2}\cdot\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^{2}+1}}\right)}{\sqrt{t^{2}+1}}dt$$

Problem reduces to,
$$H=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{3t^{2}+2}\cdot\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^{2}+1}}\right)}{\sqrt{t^{2}+1}}dt=\frac{11\pi^{2}}{288\sqrt{2}}$$

$t\to \tan t$
$$H=\int_{0}^{\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}\frac{\cos\left(t\right)}{\sin^{2}t+2}\cdot\arctan\left(\cos t\right)dt$$
Using Series Expansion for $\arctan \left(x\right)$,
$$H=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{r}}{2r+1}\int_{0}^{\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}\frac{\left(\cos t\right)^{2r+2}}{\sin^{2}t+2}dt$$

Let,
$$J_n=\int_{0}^{\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}\frac{\left(\cos t\right)^{2n}}{\sin^{2}t+2}dt$$
Which is equal to,
$$J_n=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\left(1+u^{2}\right)^{n}\left(3u^{2}+2\right)}du$$
Also,
$$\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{n}\left(3x^{2}+2\right)}=\frac{3^{n}}{3x^{2}+2}-\sum_{l=1}^{n}\frac{3^{n-l}}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{l}}$$
$$J_n=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{3^{n}}{3u^{2}+2}-\sum_{l=1}^{n}\frac{3^{n-l}}{\left(u^{2}+1\right)^{l}}\right)du$$
$$=\frac{3^{n-1}}{\sqrt{6}}\pi-\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sum_{l=1}^{n}\frac{3^{n-l}}{\left(u^{2}+1\right)^{l}}\right)du$$
$$=\frac{3^{n-1}}{\sqrt{6}}\pi-\sum_{l=1}^{n}3^{n-l}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\left(u^{2}+1\right)^{l}}du$$
Also,
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\left(u^{2}+1\right)^{l}}du=\int_{0}^{\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}\left(\cos^{2}s\right)^{l-1}ds$$
Using,
$$\left(\cos x\right)^{m}=\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{m}{2}-1}\operatorname{nCr}\left(m,k\right)\cos\left(\left(m-2k\right)x\right)+\frac{1}{2^{m}}\operatorname{nCr}\left(m,\frac{m}{2}\right)$$
For even $m$.
Therefore,
$$\int_{0}^{\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}\left(\cos x\right)^{2a-2}dx=\frac{1}{2^{2a-3}}\sum_{k=0}^{a-2}\operatorname{nCr}\left(2a-2,k\right)\frac{\sin\left(\left(2a-2-2k\right)\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\right)}{\left(2a-2-2k\right)}+\frac{1}{2^{2a-2}}\operatorname{nCr}\left(2a-2,a-1\right)\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$$

Hence,
$$J_n=\frac{3^{n-1}}{\sqrt{6}}\pi-\sum_{l=1}^{n}\frac{3^{n-l}}{2^{2l-3}}\sum_{k=0}^{l-2}\operatorname{nCr}\left(2l-2,k\right)\frac{\sin\left(\left(2l-2-2k\right)\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\right)}{\left(2l-2-2k\right)}-4\cdot3^{n}\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\sum_{l=1}^{n}\left(\frac{\left(2l-2\right)!}{12^{l}\left(l-1\right)!\left(l-1\right)!}\right)$$

Cannot take it from here.