# Is it possible to integrate $\frac{ \tan ^{-1}(t)}{t^{2n}\,\sqrt{t^2-1}}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, special-functions

Working on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763324/evaluate-int-limits-0-sqrt-2-frac13a2-2-frac-arctan-left/4763387#4763387), I faced the problem of computing:

$$I_n=\int_1^a \frac{ \tan ^{-1}(t)}{t^{2n}\,\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt$$

For a given value of $n \geq 1$, Mathematica does not face any problem and the results are quite simple.

For example, if $a=\sqrt 3$ as in the linked question
$$I_{5}=\frac{8346321-4992192 \sqrt{2}+3246848 \sqrt{6}}{58786560}\pi+$$ $$\frac{7867 \sqrt{2}-309123 \cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}{1088640}$$

**My question is** : `Is it possible to find the antiderivative even in terms of special functions ?`

Comment: There seems to be a disagreement between the title and question body.  Is $\sqrt{t^2-1}$ in the exponent or not?

Comment: En faisant des essais sur WolframAlpha pour de petites valeurs de $n$, il se dégage une forme générale. Mais je n'ai pas le courage de creuser. [$n=2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+%28x%5E%7B-6%7D%5Carctan+x%29%2F%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2-1%7D+dx), [$n=3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+%28x%5E%7B-8%7D%5Carctan+x%29%2F%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2-1%7D+dx), ...

Comment: @abiessu fixed_

Comment: @AnneBauval would you please use English? 

Comment: @LuckyChouhan Not this time. But you can use for instance [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/?hl=fr&tab=TT&sl=fr&tl=en&text=En%20faisant%20des%20essais%20sur%20Wolfram%20Alpha%20pour%20de%20petites%20valeurs%20de%20n%2C%20il%20se%20d%C3%A9gage%20une%20forme%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale.%20Mais%20je%20n%27ai%20pas%20le%20courage%20de%20creuser.%0A&op=translate).

Comment: @ErikSatie. I do not think that this answer the question about an antiderivative. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici OK I let you some funny things : $\exists a>0,x>0$ such that : $$\pi/4*x/(x+1)\left(2-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(1/n+a)^{-x}/N\right)\simeq \arctan(x)$$

Comment: @ErikSatie. May be interesting but I do not see where we would be going. But, I shall try. Cheers

Comment: Yes there is the Struve function (cheating a bit)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici playing with the parameter we have good result.

Comment: @ErikSatie. Could you go ahead, please ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $$\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}b^{-1}}{\left(x+\ln2\right)}x\left(b-\sum_{n=1}^{50}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}+a\right)^{-x}}{50}\right),a=2.8,b=2.1$$ compare with $\arctan(x)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148458/discussion-between-claude-leibovici-and-erik-satie).

Answer (score 8):

**Although I believe there is no closed form for $I_n$ for any values of $n\ge 0$, in the following post, we will provide a recurrence relation for $I_n$ in terms of well-known, closed-form functions.**

We proceed by applying IBP to $I_n$:
$$
I_n
{
=
\int_1^a\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t^{2n}\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt
=
\int_1^a\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t^{2n+1}}\frac{tdt}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}
=
\int_{t=1}^{t=a}\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t^{2n+1}}d(\sqrt{t^2-1})
\\=
\frac{\sqrt{t^2-1}\tan^{-1}t}{t^{2n+1}}\Bigg|_1^a
+(2n+1)
\int_1^a\frac{\sqrt{t^2-1}\tan^{-1}t}{t^{2n+2}}dt
-
\int_1^a\frac{\sqrt{t^2-1}}{t^{2n+1}(1+t^2)}dt
\\=
\frac{\sqrt{a^2-1}\tan^{-1}a}{a^{2n+1}}
+(2n+1)
\int_1^a\frac{(t^2-1)\tan^{-1}t}{t^{2n+2}\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt
\\-
\int_0^{\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{a}}\frac{\cos^{2n}\theta-\cos^{2n+2}\theta }{1+\cos^2\theta} d\theta
\\=
\frac{\sqrt{a^2-1}\tan^{-1}a}{a^{2n+1}}
+(2n+1)\left(
\int_1^a\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t^{2n}\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt
-
\int_1^a\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t^{2n+2}\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt
\right)
\\-
\int_0^{\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{a}} \frac{2(-1)^n}{1+\cos^2\theta}
-\cos^{2n}\theta+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2(-1)^{n-k-1}\cos^{2k}\theta d\theta
\\=
\frac{\sqrt{a^2-1}\tan^{-1}a}{a^{2n+1}}
-\sqrt2(-1)^n\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{a^2-1}{2}}
\\+(2n+1)\left(
I_n
-
I_{n+1}
\right)+J_n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2(-1)^{n-k}J_k,
}
$$
where $J_n=\int_0^{\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{a}}\cos^{2n}\theta d\theta$. The following recurrence is then deduced:
$$
I_{n+1}{=
\frac{\sqrt{a^2-1}\tan^{-1}a}{(2n+1)a^{2n+1}}
-\frac{\sqrt2(-1)^n\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{a^2-1}{2}}}{2n+1}
\\+\frac{2nI_n}{2n+1}+\frac{J_n}{2n+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2(-1)^{n-k}}{2n+1}J_k
}.
$$
For $J_n$, we can write
$$
J_n
{=
\int_0^{\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{a}}\cos^{2n}\theta d\theta
=
\int_0^{\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{a}}\cos^{2n-1}\theta \cos \theta d\theta
\\=\cos^{2n-1}\theta \sin \theta|_0^{\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{a}}+(2n-1)\int_0^{\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{a}} \sin^2\theta\cos^{2n-2}\theta
\\=\frac{\sqrt{a^2-1}}{a^{2n}}+(2n-1)\int_0^{\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{a}} \cos^{2n-2}-\cos^{2n}\theta d\theta
\\=\frac{\sqrt{a^2-1}}{a^{2n}}+(2n-1)J_{n-1}-(2n-1)J_n,
}
$$
which yields
$$
J_n=\frac{\sqrt{a^2-1}}{2na^{2n}}+\frac{2n-1}{2n}J_{n-1}\quad,\quad J_0=\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{a}.
$$

> **Conclusion**
>
> The following recurrence is given for $I_n$:
> $$
> I_{n+1}
> {=
> \frac{\sqrt{a^2-1}\tan^{-1}a}{(2n+1)a^{2n+1}}
> -\frac{\sqrt2(-1)^n\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{a^2-1}{2}}}{2n+1}
> \\+\frac{2nI_n}{2n+1}+\frac{J_n}{2n+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2(-1)^{n-k}}{2n+1}J_k
> },
> $$
> where
> $$
> J_n=\frac{\sqrt{a^2-1}}{2na^{2n}}+\frac{2n-1}{2n}J_{n-1}\quad,\quad J_0=\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{a}
> $$
> and $I_0=\int_1^a\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt$.

Comment: It is nice to have developed the recurrence relation. In terms of infinite summations, I think that we could do many. I posted one. Thanks + (+1) + cheers. :-)

Comment: Yours is nice too, as it provides an elegant relation with beta functions and harmonic numbers. Educational (+1)

Comment: By the way, how do you compute $I_0$ ?

Comment: I don't. In fact, the absence of closed-form of $I_n$ comes from that for $I_0$. This answer serves to connect $I_n$ to $I_0$ and well-known functions, which, is useful in cases where only the dependence of $I_n$ on $n$ is demanded.

Comment: This was just to tease you ! More I read your answer, more I enjoy it.  Thanks again & cheers

Comment: Nice one :D Have fun!

Comment: I have another one which would be interesting if I knew what are the $\beta_k$'s

Answer (score 4):

In terms of an infinite summation, writing
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \,\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k} \,\,t^{-(2 k+1)}$$ we have
$$I_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \,\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k} \,\,\int_1^a  t^{-(2 k+2 n+1)}\tan ^{-1}(t)$$
$$J_k=\int_1^a  t^{-(2 k+2 n+1)}\tan ^{-1}(t)$$
$$8(k+n)J_k=\pi- \frac{4\,\tan ^{-1}(a)}{ a^{2 (k+n)}}-2 i e^{i \pi  (k+n)}
   B_{-a^2}\left(-k-n+\frac{1}{2},0\right)+$$ $$\Big(H_{-\frac{2 k+2 n+3}{4} }-H_{-\frac{2 k+2 n+1}{4} }\Big)$$ and we can use the recurrence relation for the incomplete beta function.

Answer (score 4):

*Another infinite summation*
$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}(t)}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\, \alpha_k\,(t-1)^{\frac{2k-1}{2} }$$

$$J_k=\int_1^a t^{-2n}\,(t-1)^{\frac{2k-1}{2} }\,dt$$ $$J_k=\frac{\Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(2
   n-k-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (2 n)}-B_{\frac{1}{a}}\left(2
   n-k-\frac{1}{2},k+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

The coefficients of the expansion are

$$\alpha_k=\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\Bigg(\frac{\pi  }{2^{p+2}\Gamma (p+1)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_p-\beta_k\Bigg)$$ where the $\beta_k$ form the (unknown ?) sequence
$$\left\{0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{8},\frac{37}{192},\frac{49}{768},\frac
  {23}{20480},-\frac{1287}{81920},-\frac{52167}{4587520},-\frac{1
   0355}{3670016},\cdots\right\}$$

Comment: I've tried integrating a less general integral,
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos x\arctan(\cos x)\ dx$$
which is (technically doesn't fit the OP integral but similar)
$$\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}^1 \frac{t\arctan t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\ dt$$
and look into similar expansions of $\frac{\arctan t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$. I tried replicating this method (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/549028/1141581) but was unsuccessful. You might be interested in it too. Cheers.

Comment: @bob. Thanks for the suggestion ! I shall try (with a very little hope). Cheers :-)

Comment: This is a beautiful one! (+1) Do you also propose any recursive relation (or other information) for $\beta_k$?

Answer (score -1):

Not an answer just an approach

Using the well-know formula $\arctan\left(x\right)+\operatorname{arccot}\left(x\right)=\pi/2$  and $n\geq 2$ an integer ,$x>1$:

$$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{1}{x^{2n}}\cdot\frac{\arctan\left(x\right)+\operatorname{arccot}\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}dx=\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{M}a_{n}x^{2n}\right)\left(\arctan\left(x\right)+\operatorname{arccot}\left(x\right)\right)}{C_{n}x^{2M+1}}$$

For some positive constantes and coefficients .
Then for $0<x<1$

$$\arctan\left(x\right)-\operatorname{arccot}\left(x\right)=2x-\frac{2}{3}x^{3}+\frac{2}{5}x^{5}+\cdot\cdot\cdot$$

Then using the recurrence relation in the other answer we can use Ramanujan's master theorem setting $x\to 1/x$.

A conjecture :

Let $0.27<x<0.3$ and define for $q,c_i\in(0,\infty)$ :

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\frac{x-1}{x}\left(1-\frac{x-1}{8\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}\left(2+\sum_{n=3}^{P}\left(u+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-c_{n}x}\right)\right)$$

Then there exists  positive constants $k,m,\alpha>0$ such that :

$$\lim_{P\to \infty}f(x) \implies \arctan\left(x\right)-f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\left(kx^{\alpha}-m\right)=0$$

Then there is exponential integral and a possible telescoping in $I_0$.

On the other hand it's like a Troyan's horse using :

Let $x,y\in[0,1)$ then we have :

$$\arctan\left(x\right)+\arctan\left(y\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)=0$$

Comment: Can you be more specific? How does this work to integrate $\frac{ \tan ^{-1}(t)}{t^{2n}\,\sqrt{t^2-1}}$ in terms of special functions?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Maybe this is what he means? 

If we let $t\mapsto\frac{1}{t}$
$$I_n=\int_{\frac{1}{a}}^1t^{2n-1}\frac{\arctan(1/t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\ dt$$
which slightly resembles Ramanujan's master theorem.

Comment: @MartinR See the edit .

Comment: @bob Thanks for the comment I follow you and surprise! there is a formula for the Gamma's function .

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici See the interesting conjecture

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici if we go further there is something cool no very cool .cheers.