# Possible closed form of $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2)\sqrt{3-x^2-y^2-z^2} }\text{d}x\text{d}y\text{d}z$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Reviewing [the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303148/), I consider to evaluate
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}
\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2)\sqrt{3-x^2-y^2-z^2} }\text{d}x\text{d}y\text{d}z.
$$
And I quickly discover
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}
\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2)\sqrt{3-x^2-y^2-z^2} }\text{d}x\text{d}y\text{d}z\\
=\frac{9\sqrt{2}\pi }{4}\int_{\sqrt{\frac53}}^{\sqrt{2} } 
\frac{\arctan(x)}{\left ( 2x^2-3 \right )\sqrt{3x^2-5}  }\text{d}x
-\frac{\pi^3}{\sqrt{6} }+\frac{3\pi^2}{2\sqrt{6} }\arctan(2\sqrt{6} ).
$$
I don't know whether this is helpful or not. But I instinctively know it has a sufficient simple result, which only appears $\pi,\arctan$ and some quadratic irrationals.

Hopefully you are glad to reach for my hand.

Comment: are you sure the integral $\int_{\sqrt{\frac53}}^{\sqrt{2} } 
\frac{\arctan(x)}{\left ( 2x^2-3 \right )\sqrt{3x^2-5}  }\text{d}x$ can be expressed in terms of log only?

Comment: @pisco Can you help me evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln\left ( 1+\frac{1}{x}  \right ) }{(1+2x)^2} \left ( \frac{\pi^2}{12}-\ln(x)\ln(1+x)+\ln(x)^2
+\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( -\frac1x \right )   \right )\mathrm{d}x$? I don't have computer. And I know this can be done automatically. Thank you.

Comment: I think you get this from your recent problem of sine/cosine integrals, https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSXLF.png

Comment: @pisco Is $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{xK(x)^2}{1+x^2}\text{d}x
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{128}?$ This is surprisingly simple.

Comment: I think this is true.

Comment: @pisco $\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(m^2+2n^2)^s} 
=4\zeta(s)L_{-8}(s)?$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us denote by $J$ the integral to be computed. We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
J&=\int_{\sqrt{5/3}}^{\sqrt2}
\frac{\arctan x}{( 2x^2-3 )\sqrt{3x^2-5}}
\; dx
\\
&=
\int_{\sqrt{1/2}}^{\sqrt{3/5}}
x\cdot\frac{\arctan (1/x)}{( 2-3x^2 )\sqrt{3 - 5x^2}}
\; dx
=
\int_{\sqrt{1/2}}^{\sqrt{3/5}}
x\cdot \frac{\frac\pi 2-\arctan x}{( 2-3x^2 )\sqrt{3 - 5x^2}}
\; dx
\\
&=
\frac\pi2\cdot\frac 12\cdot
\int_{1/2}^{3/5}
\frac{du}{( 2-3u )\sqrt{3 - 5u}}
\; du
-
\frac 12
\int_{1/2}^{3/5}
\frac{\arctan \sqrt u}{( 2-3u )\sqrt{3 - 5u}}
\; du
\\
&=\frac \pi4\left(
\frac{\sqrt2}3-\frac{2\sqrt3}9\arctan\sqrt{\frac32}
\right)
-
\frac 1{6\sqrt 5}
\underbrace{
\color{blue}{
\int_{1/2}^{3/5}
\frac{\arctan \sqrt u}{\left( \frac 23-u \right)\sqrt{\frac 35 - u}}
\; du}}
_{=:\color{blue}{K}}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So let us compute $K$. Recall from a related post the
excellent presentation of [pisco](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/257943/pisco) the way to compute such integrals.
He also cites the book of Lewin,

> Polylogarihm and Associated Functions, Leonard Lewin, page 115-117.

We have with the conventions and definitions in *loc. cit.* the relation
$$
\color{blue}{\int_0^x\frac{\arctan\sqrt t}{(a-t)\sqrt{b-t}}\; dt}
=
\frac 1{\sqrt{a-b}}
S\left(\ 
\arctan \sqrt{\frac{b-x}{a-b}}\ ,\
\arctan \sqrt{\frac{b+1}{a-b}}\ ,\
\arctan \sqrt{\frac1a}\
\right)
\ ,
$$
where $S(\alpha, \beta,\gamma)$ is defined and computed as follows.
First of all associate the following "modulus" $k=k(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
d_1 &= \sqrt{\cos^2\alpha \cos^2\gamma-\cos^2\beta}\ ,\\
d_2 &= \sin\alpha \sin\gamma\ ,\\
k &=\frac{d_1-d_2}{d_1+d_2}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Then set for this value of $k=k(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
S(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)
&=f(\alpha,k)-f(\beta,k)+f(\gamma,k)-f(0,k)-\alpha^2+\beta^2-\gamma^2
\ ,\\
f(\alpha,k)
&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{n^2}k^n\cos(2n\alpha)
=\Re\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{n^2}(ke^{2\alpha i})^n
=\Re\operatorname{Li}_2\Big(ke^{2\alpha i}\Big)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Then $S$ has the following properties, see again *loc. cit.*:
$$
\begin{aligned}
S(0,\beta,\gamma) &= \pi(\beta-\gamma)\ ,\\
S(\alpha,\pi-2\alpha,\alpha) &= 6\cdot S\left(\alpha,\frac\pi 3,\frac \pi6\right)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
In our case we have

- $a=\frac 23$, $b=\frac35$, $x_1=\frac 12$, $x_2=\frac 35=b$,
- so $a-b=\frac1{15}$, $b-x_1=\frac 1{10}$, $b-x_2=0$,
- and associate $\alpha=\alpha_1=\arctan\sqrt{\frac{b-x_1}{a-b}}=\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1/10}{1/15}}=\arctan\sqrt{\frac 32}$, later we also need $\cos^\alpha=\frac 1{1+\tan^2\alpha}=\frac 1{5/2}=\frac 25$, and $\sin^\alpha=\frac 35$,
- $\alpha_2=\arctan\sqrt{\frac{b-x_2}{a-b}}=\arctan 0=0$,
- $\beta=\arctan\sqrt{\frac{b+1}{a-b}}=\arctan\sqrt{\frac{8/5}{1/15}}=\arctan\sqrt{24}=\pi-2\alpha$,
- $\gamma=\arctan\sqrt{\frac1a}=\arctan\sqrt{\frac32}$.

and have to compute
$$
\begin{aligned}
\color{blue}{K}&=
\frac 1{\sqrt{a-b}}
\left[\ 
S\left(\ 
\arctan \sqrt{\frac{b-x}{a-b}}\ ,\
\arctan \sqrt{\frac{b+1}{a-b}}\ ,\
\arctan \sqrt{\frac1a}\
\right)\
\right]_{x=x_1}^{x=x_2}
\\
&=
\sqrt{15}S\left(\ 0\ ,\ \arctan \sqrt {24}\ ,\ \sqrt{\frac32}\ \right) 
\\
&\qquad
-\sqrt{15}S\left(\ \arctan\sqrt{\frac32}\ ,\arctan \sqrt {24}\ ,\ \arctan\sqrt{\frac32}\ \right) 
\\
&=\sqrt{15}(S_1-S_2)\ ,\\[3mm]
S_1 &:=S(\alpha_1,\beta,\gamma)=S(0,\beta,\gamma)=\pi(\beta-\gamma)=\pi\left(\arctan \sqrt{24} - \arctan\sqrt{\frac32}\right)
\\
&=\pi\arctan\frac{3\sqrt 6}{14}\ ,
\\
S_2 &=S(\alpha_2,\beta,\gamma)=S(\alpha,2\pi-\alpha,\alpha)=
6\cdot S\left(\alpha,\frac\pi 3,\frac \pi6\right)\ ,
\\
&\qquad \text{ and only $S_2$ has to be computed to complete.}
\\
&\qquad \text{ Above, there are two way to do this. Same modulus $k$.}
\\
k\left(\alpha,\beta,\gamma\right)
&%=\frac{d_1-d_2}{d_1+d_2}
=\frac
{\sqrt{\frac25\cdot\frac 25-\frac 1{25}}-\frac 35}
{\sqrt{\frac25\cdot\frac 25-\frac 1{25}}+\frac 35}
=
\frac{\sqrt 3-3}{\sqrt 3+3}
=-\frac 12(\sqrt 3-1)^2=\sqrt 3-2\ ,
\\
k\left(\alpha,\frac\pi 3,\frac \pi6\right)
&=\frac
{\sqrt{\frac25\cdot\frac 34-\frac 14}-\frac 12\cdot\sqrt{\frac 35}}
{\sqrt{\frac25\cdot\frac 34-\frac 14}+\frac 12\cdot\sqrt{\frac 35}}
=
\frac{\sqrt{\frac 15}-\sqrt{\frac 35}}{\sqrt{\frac 15}+\sqrt{\frac 35}}
=-\frac 12(\sqrt 3-1)^2=\sqrt 3-2\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$

We have now an explicit expression in terms of dilogarithmic values and "easier" data for the integral $K=\sqrt{15}(S_1-S_2)$,
thus also for $J$. Here, $S_1$ is also simple, but $S_2$ involves the (real part of the) dilogarithm $\operatorname{Li}_2$ computed in points like
$$
(\sqrt 3-2)\cdot\left(\sqrt{\frac 25}-i\sqrt{\frac 35}\right)^2\ ,\\
(\sqrt 3-2)\cdot\frac 12(-1+\sqrt 3)\ ,\qquad
(\sqrt 3-2)\cdot\frac 12(1+i\sqrt 3)\ ,\qquad
(\sqrt 3-2)\cdot 1\ .
$$
And there is no K-theoretic trick to get something like a multiple of $\pi$.

I have to stop here, computations were done without double check, there may be some, but the computational line applies at any rate.

Comment: Related: https://www.georges-vidiani.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/3-CoxeterInt.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Though I know it probably can't be solved elegantly, I still want to mention something about the integral relation given by me.
In fact, the following generalization holds.

> For non-negative integers $\alpha,\beta$ satisfying $\alpha\ge\beta$, define $$I(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{[0,1]^{\alpha-\beta}}
> \frac{\text{d}x_1...\text{d}x_{\alpha-\beta}}{(1+x_1^2)...(1+x_{\alpha-\beta}^2)\sqrt{\alpha+\beta-x_1^2-...-x_{\alpha-\beta}^2}}.$$
> If $\beta=\alpha$, it equals
> $$
> I(\alpha,\alpha)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\alpha}}.
> $$
> Then
> $$\sum_{0\le\beta\le\alpha}c_\beta\pi^{\beta}I(\alpha,\beta)=0.$$
> Where the coefficients $c_\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$.

- For example, let $\alpha=2$. We simply calculates
  $$
  I(2,0)=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{d}x\text{d}y}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2} } 
  =\frac\pi2\arctan\left ( \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}  \right ),\quad I(2,1)=\int_{0}^{1}  \frac{\text{d}x}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{3-x^2} } 
  =\frac12\arctan\left ({\sqrt{2}}  \right ),\quad I(2,2)=\frac12.
  $$
  And immediately we have
  $$
  2I(2,0)-4\pi I(2,1)+\pi^2 I(2,2)=0.
  $$
- For $\alpha=3$,
  $$
  2I(3,0)-9\pi I(3,1)+6\pi^2 I(3,2)-\pi^3 I(3,3)=0.
  $$
  And this is just the claimed one.
- For $\alpha=4$,
  $$
  2I(4,0)-16\pi I(4,1)+20\pi^2 I(4,2)-8\pi^3 I(4,3)+\pi^4 I(4,4)=0.
  $$
  And we have
  $$
  \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}
  \frac{8\pi-\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{5-x^2-y^2-z^2}{3-x^2-y^2-z^2} }
  \right) }{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2)\sqrt{5 -x^2-y^2-z^2} }\text{d}x\text{d}y\text{d}z
  =5\pi^2\sqrt{2}\int_{\sqrt{\frac75}}^{\sqrt{\frac32} } 
  \frac{\arctan(x)}{\left ( 3x^2-4 \right )\sqrt{5x^2-7}  }\text{d}x
  -\frac{3\pi^4}{4\sqrt{2} }+\frac{\pi^3}{\sqrt{2} }\arctan(4\sqrt{3}).
  $$
- For $1\le\alpha\le10$, the coefficients are listed below.
  \begin{matrix}\hline
    \alpha& c_0 &c_1 &  c_2&  c_3&  c_4& c_5 & c_6 &  c_7&  c_8&  c_9& c_{10}\\\hline
  1&  2&  -1&  .& . & . & . &  .&  .& . &  .& .\\
   2 &  2&  -4&  1&  .& . & . &  .&  .&  .&  .& .\\
    3&  2&  -9&  6&  -1&.  & . & . & . & .  & . & .\\
    4&  2&  -16&  20&  -8&  1& . &  .& . & . & . & .\\
    5&  2&  -25&  50&  -35&  10&  -1& . & . &.  & . & .\\
   6 &  2&  -36&  105&  -112&  54&  -12&  1&  .& . &  .& .\\
    7&  2&  -49&  196&  -294&  210& -77 & 14 & -1 & . &  .&. \\
    8&  2&  -64&  336&  -672&  660&  -352&  104& -16& 1 & .&.\\
   9 &  2&  -81&  540&  -1386&  1782&  -1287&  546& -135 &  18& -1 &. \\
   10 &  2&  -100&  825&  -2640&  4290&  -4004&  2275& -800 & 170 & -20 & 1\\
  \hline
  \end{matrix}